# Converting Pandas DateTimeIndex to elapsed time from a date

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert the datetime index to an elapsed time in days from a particular date (a negative number for dates prior to the target date, positive after). Hypothetically, it could be as simple as subtracting the date from the index per below but that spits out a TypeError:

```
from pandas.io.data import DataReader
from datetime import datetime
prices = DataReader('^GSPC',  'yahoo', datetime(2010,1,1), datetime(2015,6,15))[['Adj Close']]
prices.index = prices.index - datetime(2012,1,1) #<------------ TypeError
print prices
```

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Hmm, your code worked for me using pandas 0.16.2, numpy 1.9.2 ython 3.3.4 64-bit can you post your versions, thanks

Comment: That's good to know. Using an older version 0.13.1 that shipped with Anaconda. Will see if I can upgrade. Thanks!